# Emacs yanking (pasting) from website always yields character code 160 instead of SPC

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, character-encoding

When copying code from the web (usually using Chrome in Ubuntu) I am frustrated by the fact that Emacs inserts blank  spaces of `Char:   (160, #o240, #xa0)` wherever there should be a space character, `Char: SPC (32, #o40, #x20)`. This appears fine in the editor but as soon as I try to execute the code I get errors. How can I make Emacs convert `&nbsp;` entities into normal space characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query-replace` (M-%) to convert the characters.  Copy-paste can help you enter the non-breaking space.

Comment: That's normally what I do. Any way to avoid having to do this?

Comment: Possibly, but it wouldn't really be an emacs question anymore.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm thinking about some kind of Emacs setting or macro.

Comment: Unless you're using some weird add-on, Emacs has no reason to change space characters behind your back.  The nbsps more likely come from Chrome.

Comment: You are right. I see this is an old issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16926